# transform siblings nodes to imbricated nodes

Tags: xslt

I am experiencing issues with an XSLT. I have a set of sibling nodes( `<level>` ) inside `<source>`, which I'd like to transform in an imbrication of nodes (i.e. each level would render inside its previous sibling).

### XML INPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sources> 
    <source mode="manual"  name="test1">
                <level>blablabla Level1</level>
                <level>this is the second level</level>
                <level>this is the third level</level>
    </source>
</sources>
```

### Intended Output

the output I want is an imbricated html version of this (abridged, the imbrication is the thing here):

```
   <form class="source manual">
    source &gt; <input value="test1" name="sourceName" type="text">

    <!-- LEVEL #1 -->
    <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>1</strong></p>
    <div class="deepnessContainer">
         <!-- LEVEL #2 -->
         next-level:
         <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>2</strong></p>
         <div class="deepnessContainer">
              <!-- LEVEL #3 -->
              next-level:
              <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>3</strong></p>
         </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

unfortunatly the XSL I composed fail, here the source (I tried to shorten but):

### XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="sources">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Main template here -->
    <xsl:template match="source[@mode='manual']">
        <form class="source manual">
            source &gt; <input type="text" name="sourceName" value="{@name}" />

            <!-- Here's what I call first the recursion 
                the parameter is the # of the <level> 
                that should be processed -->
            <xsl:call-template name="sourceLevelRecursion">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel">1</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Recursion template -->
    <xsl:template name="sourceLevelRecursion">
        <xsl:param name="currentLevel" />

            <!-- this apply-templates should apply on only 
                one node because of the selector but it won't -->
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="deepnessHeader" select="./level[$currentLevel]">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel"><xsl:value-of select="$currentLevel" /></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:if test="level[$currentLevel+1]">
            <div class="deepnessContainer">
                    <!-- Recursion Call here -->
            <xsl:call-template name="sourceLevelRecursion">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentLevel"><xsl:value-of select="$currentLevel+1" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
                </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template mode="deepnessHeader" match="level">
        <xsl:param name="currentLevel" />
            <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong><xsl:value-of select="$currentLevel" /></strong></p>
        </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

### Unfortunate output

the final erroneous output I obtain is:

```
   <form class="source manual">
    source &gt; <input value="test1" name="sourceName" type="text">

    <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>1</strong></p>
    <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>1</strong></p>
    <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>1</strong></p>

    <div class="deepnessContainer">
      next-level:

      <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>2</strong></p>
      <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>2</strong></p>
      <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>2</strong></p>

      <div class="deepnessContainer">
        next-level:

        <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>3</strong></p>
        <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>3</strong></p>
        <p class="deepnessIndicator">Deepness: <strong>3</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

As you can see, the apply:

`<xsl:apply-templates mode="deepnessHeader" select="./level[$currentLevel]">`

matched by
 `<xsl:template mode="deepnessHeader" match="level">`

is matched thrice, one time per each `<level>` in the source XML. But, the selector in apply-templates is supposed to select only one node isn't it ?

Comment: PS: I ran my XSLT test with this: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution and for explanation of the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="deepnessHeader" 
   select="./level[position()=$currentLevel]">
```

**XSLT 1.0 is "weakly typed". The XSLT processor doesn't know that the value contained by the `$currentLevel` should be treated as an integer**.

Therefore `$currentLevel` is treated as a boolean -- as any non-integer expression inside a predicate should. However, if the actual value can be cast to an integer, then any integer value different than 0 is treated as `true()` and the whole predicate is `true()` so nothing is filtered out.

**Remember**:

In XPath 1.0 any `Expr[someInteger]` ,  where `someInteger` is an integer literal, is a shorthand for: `Expr[position() = someInteger]`

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly !

Then, two more questions come to me:
why the test <xsl:if test="level[$currentLevel+1]"> fails as I wanted in the first place ? should'nt it be always true ?

Comment: And second question, you mentionned XSLT 1.0, so is it different in XSLT2 ? (just curiosity, cannot use xslt2 cause I'm performing the transform in the browser)

Comment: @BiAiB: Your first question: in `level[$currentLevel+1]` the XSLT processor knows that the expression inside the predicate is of numeric type (because of the addition operator). Therefore it treats this as shorthand for: `level[position() = $currentLevel+1]`

Comment: that means `<xsl:apply-templates mode="deepnessHeader" select="./level[$currentLevel+0]">` could have been a fixup too so?

Comment: @BiAiB: Your second question: In XPath 2.0/XSLT 2.0 there is strong typing and a variable may have an explicit type declared for itself. If for example you have: `<xsl:variable name="currentLevel" select="someExpression" as="xs:integer"/>` then in `level[$currentLevel]` the XSLT processor knows that the expression inside the predicate is of type `xs:integer` and expands the shorthand.